# Problems with Doctrine 2.0

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine, doctrine-orm

**1-) In old version i use syncronizeWithArray method of Doctrine_Record, it's save a lote of time.**

Version 2.0 does not provide it?

**2-) In code below flush command generate 3 records on database, its a bug of 2.0?**

```
public function indexAction()
{

   $em = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap')->em

   $obj = new Entity\Obj();
   $obj->name = "teste";
   $obj->last_name = "teste";
   $em->persist($obj);
   $em->flush();
}
```

**Obs: The indexAction is called onlyOneTime.**

**Problem 2 Solved. its my fault!!**

Comment: if you have two questions, please ask them seperatly. if its resolved and you dont want to provide information for others to solve it, just edit it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version 2 doctrine entities don't extend from a base class anymore. Therefore the functionaly `synchronizeWithArray` isn't in the model anymore.

You could however implement ArrayAcces to work with Entities as if with arrays.
See [implementing array access in the reference](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/cookbook/implementing-arrayaccess-for-domain-objects.html?highlight=array).

Comment: Thanks man!!, looking for more i found a way to implement behaviors, http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine2-behaviours-nutshell.